# Column-wise copy C/C++ array

Tags: c++, c, multidimensional-array

I have various text files were matrices are stored.  I can read these in and save them out as I desire.  However, in some cases I want to discard columns of the matrix.  I can do this via nested loops but I think there should be a way to do this with `memcpy` or something similar.  Here is an example:

```
#include <string.h>

using namespace std;

int main(){

int a1[4][3];

int count(0);

for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i){
    for (int j = 0; j < 3; ++j){
        a1[i][j] = count;
        ++count;
    }
}

int a2[4][2];

memcpy(a2, a1, sizeof(int) * 8);

int a3[4][2];
int *t = &a1[0][1];
memcpy(a3, t, sizeof(int) * 8);

return 0;
}
```

Since the array is stored as row major `memcpy` the results of `a2` and `a3` are integers `0-7` and `1-8` respectively.  What I want is a way to get integers

```
0 1
3 4
6 7
9 10
```

instead.  These are the first 2 columns of `a1`.  I can do this if I define `aTransposed[3][4]` and use it as:

```
int aTransposed[3][4];
for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i){
    for(int j = 0; j < 4; ++j){
        aTransposed[i][j] = a1[j][i];
    }
}
memcpy(a2, aTransposed, sizeof(int) * 8);
```

`a2` will contain the correct values but in the wrong positions.

My question is how can I copy any given column or columns from one array into another without using loops?  Either a C or C++ solution is fine.  Try to avoid additional libraries like Eigen or Boost.

**EDIT**
To those of you that get wrapped around the C/C++ tag.  There is nothing in this that must be C or C++.  Either way will work.  Yes the snippet I wrote is in C++ but it can be easily be done in either.  I am trying to find a solution within either language.  Hence both tags.

Comment: Either C or C++, pick one.

Comment: @CoryKramer this will not compile in C.

Comment: @Rabbid76 that is interesting.  I wondered how to start at a column other than 0 so I tried this `int *t = &a1[i][var1]; memcpy(a2[i], t, sizeof(int) * var2);` where I can change `var1` and `var2` based on my needs.

Comment: Regardless of the edit, this should either be language agnostic if the OP only needs an algorithm or should pick a language they want it in as opposed to giving an arbitrary selection of languages answers may be in. It would make just as much sense to say it should be in either Java or Fortran.

Comment: There is no C/C++ tag. But we happily will add one if you provide a link to the specification of that language C/C++. Until then there still are the two different languages C and C++ only. You still should pick one. Otherwise the question should be closed as too broad. Using C programming style in C++ and vice versa is just bad coding.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The memory layout for an object declared as:

```
int a1[4][3];
```

is

```
|                   a1                          |

|   a1[0]   |                       |   a1[3]   |
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
|           |           |           |           |
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
```

The memory layout for an object declared as:

```
int a2[4][2];
```

is

```
|              a2               |

| a2[0] |               | a2[3] |
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
|       |       |       |       |
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
```

The elements that define the third column of `a1` are:

```
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
|         x |         x |         x |         x |
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
```

The elements that define the second column of `a2` are:

```
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
|     x |     x |     x |     x |
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
```

Since the elements that define a column are not in contiguous memory, you
cannot use `memcpy` to copy a column from `a1` to `a2`. Using a loop is the only way to copy a column from `a1` to `a2`.